# How to adjust code to make a sign up form

Tags: c#, sql

I am making a project in C# Windows forms. So far I have figured out how to code a login form from YouTube but I don't know how to use the same method to make a sign up form. Here is the code below and I am hoping someone can help make the adjustments so it inserts the username and password into database instead for a user.

```
try
{

    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblLogin where username = @username and password = @password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.fill(dt);
    if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("login successful");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex); 
}
```

Incase I have copied the code wrong the link to the video is here: https://youtu.be/nh-fleqcds4

Comment: can you make the code readable please?

Comment: I'm on phone so it came out like that. I left a YouTube link below it's much easier to see it on there.

Comment: In the sign up form you want to do the same thing? select the user with username and password from the database? then what's the difference between login and singup?

Comment: I want to change the code so instead of checking if the username and login is present in the database I want to add the inputs from text box into the data base

Answer (score 0):

That should be your solution.
You have to insert your textbox values instead of select them.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblLogin(username, password)values(@username, @password)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex); 
}
```

[This Tutorial is very helpful in my opinion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bQfxbSj4tg&list=PL4Qls_AA7vWKaDjq6L9z7JQS3Y4brOKmK)